# How to redirect a user to a certain webpage base of a code they enter through php

Tags: php

When a user enters 1234p they will go to google.com, if 5678n they will go to yahoo.com and so on. Right now the code I have only worked for 1 page with 1234

```
<?php

session_start();
$redirect = true; 
$url_redirect = 'http://www.google.com'; 



$pass = "1234";
$msg;

if (isset($_POST['btn_go'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['count'] >= 3) {
        $msg['msg'] = "max_count";
    } else {
        $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
        if ($pwd == $pass) {
            $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
            $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 1;
            $msg['msg'] = "ok";
            if ($redirect) {
                $msg['redirect'] = 1;
                $msg['url'] = $url_redirect;
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
            $msg['msg'] = "wrong";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($msg);

} else {
    echo "wrong";
}

?>
```

Comment: This question seems incomplete, please show your code so we can review and find any error. Is a little hard to understand at all how are processed input, where to show etc.

Comment: I'm having a problem posting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a `switch` statement  --  Assuming you know how to set the variable `$page` in this example .. :

```
<?php
session_start();
$redirect = true; 


if (isset($_POST['btn_go'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['count'] >= 3) {
        $msg['msg'] = "max_count";
    } else {
        $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);

        switch ($pwd) {
            case '1234p':
                $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
                $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 1;
                $msg['msg'] = "ok";
                if ($redirect) {
                    $msg['redirect'] = 1;
                    $msg['url'] = 'http://google.com';
                }
                break;
            case '5678n':
                $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
                $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 1;
                $msg['msg'] = "ok";
                if ($redirect) {
                    $msg['redirect'] = 1;
                    $msg['url'] = 'http://yahoo.com';
                }
                break;

            default:
                $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
                $msg['msg'] = "wrong";
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($msg);

} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

Your question only mentions `php` so I am assuming you're getting your input from a `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

**UPDATE**  I have Edited my answer to better fit your code .. I still think that a `switch` statement is best suited for the output you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks, Zak but can you please look at my code again. I was having an issue pasting it.

Comment: Updated to better reflect what a `switch` statement looks like inside your code .. Think of it as a different "cleaner" way of doing multiple `if` / `else if` statements.

Comment: Wow, amazing!!! Works great! I just have one more question.  Suppose I have over a thousand pages to do, would this be the best way

Comment: If that works for ya, go ahead and accept my answer :)

Comment: Ok. Doing it now but I was just wondering if this would be the best way if i had a lot of pages.

Comment: If you have that many pages .. I would recommend storing them in a database and making this a data-driven snippet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some code refacto but I think your logic is here.

Don't hesitate to ask if something isn't clear

```
<?php

session_start(); 

// Define an array with pass as key and the value is the url to redirect
$passToUrl = [
    '1234p' => 'http://www.google.com',
    '5678n' => 'http://yahoo.com'
];

if (isset($_POST['btn_go'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['count'] >= 3) {
        $msg['msg'] = "max_count";
    } else if(array_key_exists('pwd', $_POST)) { // Test if the user submitted a pass before using it
        $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
        // The pass is defined in the array 
        if (array_key_exists($pwd, $passToUrl)) {
            $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
            $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 1;
            // let's redirect to the good url
            header('Location: ' . $passToUrl[$pwd]);
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
            $msg['msg'] = "wrong";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($msg);

} else {
    echo json_encode(["msg" => "wrong"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to accept the code but it doesn't go to any URL. If I enter the wrong code it says "incorrect" but the right code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please add a `echo('A custom message'); inside each condition statements to debug why the script don't go in the redirect part